# y-axis too short using levelplot R

Tags: r, plot, levelplot

I'm using the lattice package in R language. My data is stored in "Rate_out", which is a 100*1100 matrix of numeric elements. However, I find that the output figure is too long in the x-axis and too-short in the y-axis, which is shown as following.

[image]

How can I compress the x-axis to let the figure to be a square? Note that I don't want to use xlim to cut off my raw data.

```
require(lattice)
levelplot(Rate_out, at=seq(0, 2, 0.1), xlab = "Grahp_NO", ylab ="10*epsilon",
  main = "Rate=mean/mean'",
  col.regions = terrain.colors(100)
)
```

Comment: Use xlim=c(0,500) to reduce x-axis

Comment: Thank you very much! It works to the figure. However, this method seems discarding the data in (500, 1100). Is this true?